# WPF horizontal ItemsControl with usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-controls, itemscontrol, horizontallist

I'm trying to design a horizontal stack of UserControls. I have a `UserControl` named `MiniControl` and an `ObservableCollection<MiniControl>` in my `ViewModel` named `MiniVideos`. In the `Window` I'm trying to put all together I have this code:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="items" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MiniVideos}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightGray"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

When I run the code, it is not working as expected and I have the following error in output:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='MiniControl'.

Any idea?